# Is slf4j useless?

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j, logback

There was a time when the use of *slf4j* was recommended to hide the implementation of the logging system. In that time there was people that felt the need to switch their logging system, but that is something that I haven't seen in many years.

Given that currently most Java developers use exclusively *Logback* or *log4j* and these libraries are mature enough, wouldn't it make more sense get rid of the wrapper and use the library straight away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Logback is implementing SLF4J's interfaces.  Hence, you need to use SLF4J if you use Logback.

SLF4J does more than hiding implementation.  One of the most important reason to use SLF4J is its ability to bridge different logging implementations.  Just bear in mind that, you can choose your logging library that your code use, but you cannot choose which logging library that your other libraries use.

For example, if you use Log4j 1.x directly, and you are using another library (let's call it A) that is using JUL.  What will happen is, even you have properly configure your log4.xml, log message from A is not going to the log file you configured, because it is handled by JUL.

SLF4J provides bridges so that once you put correct bridges in your classpath, it will redirect the call of other logging library to SLF4J.  Use the above example, assuming now you use SLF4J and use Log4J as its implementation, and then you add JUL-to-SLF4J bridge jar to your classpath.  Code in library A will still log using JUL, but such log will be redirected to SLF4J, and hence SLF4J will capture those log and use your desired logging library (e.g. Log4J) to capture all log message.  It is something you cannot do if you use your desired logging library directly.

With the above example, if you are developer of A, you will also know that it is not a good idea to stick to a specific logging library implementation, because it is going to cause a lot of trouble to user of your library.  By using SLF4J, it also solve the problem, so that the user of your library can choose whatever logging backend they want, and your code in A will work seamlessly.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what you are doing.

It is usually always recommended to abstract, although in certain cases more abstraction makes code more difficult to maintain and follow, thus, shipping an application which is bound to a particular logger implementation will probably lead to something simpler, although much less flexible should things change down the line.

That being said, imagine you are developing a 3rd party framework. Shipping your own framework with it's own logger can cause problems down the line because maybe who ever is consuming your product already have their own logger, and using your framework which also has its own logger might cause confusion/setup issues.

Using something such as SLF4J would allow your framework to provide logs but use the logger which who ever is using your product wants.